# job.jar does not exist while running map reduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a hortonworks distribution (2.2.6.0-2800) of Hadoop which runs mapreduce job based on yarn, and I have a simple map reduce job which reads compressed data files from hdfs, does some processing over it and then this data is saved in hbase with bulk load

Here is my program that does it

```
    final Configuration hadoopConfiguration = new Configuration();
    configuration.set(“yarn.resourcemanager.address”, “XXXXXX”);
    configuration.set(“yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address”, “XXXXXX”);
    configuration.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn”);
    configuration.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir", “XXXXXXXX”);

    final Job job = Job.getInstance(hadoopConfiguration, "migration");
    job.setJarByClass(BlitzService.class);
    job.setMapperClass(DataMigrationMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(KeyValue.class);
    job.setReducerClass(DataMigrationReducer.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(DataMigrationReducer.class);
    HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, filesToProcess.toArray(new Path[filesToProcess.size()]));
    HFileOutputFormat2.setOutputPath(job, new Path(SOME PATH));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

This should be a very simple thing to run but I am facing this exception while running the job

```
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,222] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /172.30.0.147:8032
WARN  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,383] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,492] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 16
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,561] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:16
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,719] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1437695344326_0002
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,842] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1437695344326_0002
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,867] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-172-30-0-147.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/proxy/application_1437695344326_0002/
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:20,868] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1437695344326_0002
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:35,994] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Job job_1437695344326_0002 running in uber mode : false
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:35,995] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:43,053] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1437695344326_0002_m_000001_1000, Status : FAILED
File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1437695344326_0002/job.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1437695344326_0002/job.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


INFO  [2015-07-23 23:53:44,075] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1437695344326_0002_m_000002_1000, Status : FAILED
File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1437695344326_0002/job.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1437695344326_0002/job.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: did you try to change the "mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir" path to your hadoop directory?

Comment: it was already set

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir</name>
    <value>/user/mapred/staging</value>
  </property>

Comment: Try to change this to your staging directory. check yarn-site.xml properties for the same. instead of hadoop tmp dir in core-site.xml try to set to your mapreduce jobtracker staging root dir using yarn-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390227/hadoop-jobs-fail-when-submitted-by-users-other-than-yarn-mrv2-or-mapred-mrv1) could be similar to this. Once you verify if the jar is existing in the above directory(/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1437695344326_0002/), see if the same permissions are being set as mentioned in link. Otherwise you can add similar authorization property

Comment: I am nor sure whether its the same, the job is being run as a root user and the jar does not exists in the path it is complaining about.

Answer (score -1):

I've met a same problem. It has nothing to do with the JAR dir. Make sure that your inputpaths are right. check your files path filesToProcess

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, filesToProcess.toArray(new Path[filesToProcess.size()]));
```